dot in REGEXP_LIKE pattern
begin
    if NOT REGEXP_LIKE('-', '^[[:alpha:][:digit:][:space:]-./]*$')  then
        dbms_output.put_line ('NOT') ;
    else
        dbms_output.put_line ('OK') ;
    end if ;
end ;

it gives: OK
why the second gives: NOT ?
begin
    if NOT REGEXP_LIKE('-', '^[[:alpha:][:digit:][:space:].-/]*$')  then
        dbms_output.put_line ('NOT') ;
    else
        dbms_output.put_line ('OK') ;
    end if ;
end ;

the only change is position of dot and minus in pattern

A simplified question would be REGEXP_LIKE('-', '^[.-/]*$') vs REGEXP_LIKE('-', '^[-./]*$')

please post create table with insert into and wanted result a full [mre]

Not an answer to your question, but there is something fishy with the / at the end of your reg.exps. REGEXP_LIKE('-', '^[[:alpha:][:digit:][:space:].-]*$')and REGEXP_LIKE('-', '^[[:alpha:][:digit:][:space:].-]*$') both evaluates to TRUE.

I see 2 comments on how to make question more simple.
For Lennart REGEXP_LIKE('-', '^[.-/]$') vs REGEXP_LIKE('-', '^[-./]$') is more simple.
I don't think so.
In my explanation you need only copy-paste to get result.
It is simple TO USE and TO CHECK.

Because the dash ("-") between two characters inside the bracket expression indicates a range of characters, so [.-/] means any character between "." and "/". The dash at the beginning or at the end is treated as a dash.

Thanks. It is stupid in stack that I can't vote answer to my own question :)
